# Passing arguments to Python script in Java

Tags: java, python, jython

I'm running a python script in a java class like this:

```
PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), System.getProperties(), new String[0]);
interp.execfile("C:\\Users\\user1\\workspace\\Projectx\\script.py");
```

The problem is that script.py usually takes commandline arguments like this:

> python script.py -i C:/diretory/path -o C:/directory/path

Is it possible to pass those arguments via the PythonIntepereter in Java ?

**Update:**

Thx to Juned Ahsan my code now looks like this:

```
String[] args = {"-i " + lawlinkerIfolder.toString() + " -o " + lawlinkerOfolder.toString()};
PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), System.getProperties(), args);
interp.execfile("C:\\Users\\user1\\workspace\\Projectx\\script.py");
```

But the script is still not getting any arguments.

Am I using this correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last argument in your below call is for command line arguments:

```
PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), System.getProperties(), new String[0]);
```

From [PythronInterpreter javadocs](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/util/PythonInterpreter.html):

> **initialize**
>
> public static void initialize(Properties preProperties,
>                                 Properties postProperties,
>                                 String[] argv)
>
> Initializes the Jython runtime. This should only be called once,
>   before any other Python objects (including PythonInterpreter) are
>   created. Parameters: preProperties - A set of properties. Typically
>   System.getProperties() is used. preProperties override properties from
>   the registry file. postProperties - Another set of properties. Values
>   like python.home, python.path and all other values from the registry
>   files can be added to this property set. postProperties override
>   system properties and registry properties.
>   **argv - Command line arguments, assigned to sys.argv.**

Comment: thank you that looks promising. However I'm unsure of how to use it. I now have                                              `String[] args = {lawlinkerIfolder.toString(), lawlinkerOfolder.toString()}; but the script is still not working properly. 
  PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), System.getProperties(), args);`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found it could be resolved by using "interned" string, i.e.,

```
for (int i = 0; i args.length; ++i) {
    args[i] = args[i].intern();
}
```

I am using Jython 2.5.3.  Hope this will help.